# Where I can find the .rtf locations I uploaded in XML Publisher of Oracle EBS R12? I just wanted to know the locations of all the rtf I published?

Tags: rtf, oracle-ebs, xml-publisher

Where I can find the .rtf locations I uploaded in XML Publisher of Oracle EBS R12? I just wanted to know the locations of all the rtf I published?

Please tell me the command of linux through which i can know..or anything

Answer (score 1):

BI Publisher .rtf templates are not uploaded to OS level, they are stored as blobs in DB table xdo_lobs.file_data as below (see full query in Blitz Report [XDO Publisher Datasources](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/xdo-publisher-datasources/))

```
select
xtv.template_name,
xtv.template_code,
(
select
xl.file_name
from
xdo_lobs xl
where
xtv.template_code=xl.lob_code and
xtv.application_short_name=xl.application_short_name and
(
(
xl.lob_type='TEMPLATE' and
xl.xdo_file_type<>'RTF' and
xtv.template_type_code=xl.xdo_file_type
or
xl.lob_type='TEMPLATE_SOURCE' and
xl.xdo_file_type in ('RTF','RTF-ETEXT')
) and
xtv.default_language=xl.language and
xtv.default_territory=xl.territory
or
xl.lob_type='TEMPLATE_SOURCE' and
xl.xdo_file_type='RTF' and
xtv.mls_language=xl.language and
xtv.mls_territory=xl.territory and
exists (
select null from xdo_lobs xl2
where xl2.lob_type='MLS_TEMPLATE' and
xtv.application_short_name=xl2.application_short_name and
xtv.template_code=xl2.lob_code and
xtv.default_language=xl2.language and
xtv.default_territory=xl2.territory) and
not exists (
select null from xdo_lobs xl3
where
xl3.lob_type='TEMPLATE_SOURCE' and
xtv.application_short_name=xl3.application_short_name and
xtv.template_code=xl3.lob_code and
xtv.default_language=xl3.language and
xtv.default_territory=xl3.territory)
)
) default_template_file,
(select xl.file_name from xdo_lobs xl where xl.lob_type='TEMPLATE_SOURCE' and xtv.application_short_name=xl.application_short_name and xtv.template_code=xl.lob_code and xtv.mls_language=xl.language and xtv.mls_territory=xl.territory) mls_template_file
from
xdo_templates_vl xtv
```

If you want to see them as clob, you need a function like [xxen_util.blob_to_clob](https://www.enginatics.com/xxen_util/true).

```
select
xl.lob_type,
xl.application_short_name,
xl.lob_code,
xl.file_name,
xl.language,
xl.territory,
xxen_util.blob_to_clob(xl.file_data) file_clob
from
xdo_lobs xl
where
xl.file_name like '%.rtf' and
xl.lob_type in ('TEMPLATE','TEMPLATE_SOURCE')
```